# Bluetooth mouse pairs but does not connect

Tags: mouse, dell, bluetooth

I've installed Ubuntu 15.04 on a DELL XPS 13 notebook (model 9343, bios A03). After some tweaking, I've manage to make the bluetooth work (Broadcom Corp. BCM20702A0 Bluetooth). However, I manage to pair my bluetooth mouse (Dell WM615) but it does not connect. I tried already several things, but at this moment I'm a bit stuck. Does anybody have an idea what may be the issue?

I attach some info:

```
ludwik@ludwik-XPS-13:~$ lsusb
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0c45:670c Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f3:20d0 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:216f Broadcom Corp. BCM20702A0 Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. M105 Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
ludwik@ludwik-XPS-13:~$ dmesg | grep firmware
[    2.741704] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: firmware hci_ver=06 hci_rev=1624 lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=220e
```

I realised that the pairing wasn't successful. I mean the bluetooth manager said that it was, but when I look at dmesg output, I have those two error lines:

```
[ 1214.194988] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_station : Wrong Mac address, mac = d0:c7:89:cd:d0:ef   profile =d0:c7:89:cd:d0:e0
[ 1359.069997] Bluetooth: HCI request failed to create LE connection: status 0x0c
```

So I dumped also the HCI raw data and during the pairing it does that:

```
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4
    Inquiry Cancel (0x01|0x0002) ncmd 1
    status 0x00
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4
    LE Create Connection (0x08|0x000d) status 0x00 ncmd 1
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4
    LE Start Encryption (0x08|0x0019) status 0x00 ncmd 1
> HCI Event: Encrypt Change (0x08) plen 4
    status 0x00 handle 64 encrypt 0x01
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4
    Disconnect (0x01|0x0006) status 0x00 ncmd 1
> HCI Event: Disconn Complete (0x05) plen 4
    status 0x00 handle 64 reason 0x16
    Reason: Connection Terminated by Local Host
```

Comment: Does the mouse even work for a few seconds?  Maybe interference with the battery indicator, bug 1098959.

Comment: It doesn't work even for a moment..

Comment: Any other ideas?

Comment: As suggested in the bug, did you try killing the upowerd and the indicator-power-service?

Comment: Yes, I've tried. When I kill upowerd or indicator-power-service I get the message: no process found.

Comment: I found out that the pairing is not done properly. I've edited my original post, and added the dmesg output and also the hcidump during pairing. Does it make any sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe what is happening is that you have a mouse that uses the new low-energy bluetooth mode that was introduced in bluez5 and your running bluez4. I have a similar situation with my Microsoft Arc Mouse.

In this line: `[ 1359.069997] Bluetooth: HCI request failed to create LE connection: status 0x0c` the `LE` connection refers to this new low-energy mode that is only in bluez5.

**A Little Background on Bluez**

Bluez is the bluetooth driver and, from what I've found online, each major update for it seems to break a lot of things. When bluez4 was introduced, it wasn't backwards compatible with bluez3 and so it took a long time for Linux to upgrade to bluez4 as every program had to be ported to bluez4. To go along with that, according to [this article](http://blog.projectnibble.org/2010/08/08/how-ubuntus-broken-bluetooth-support-came-to-be/), apparently Bluez has horrible documentation and so took forever to figure out how to update programs to use it.

When bluez5 came out, it appears that also broke backwards compatibility. See [this page](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/desktop-v-bluez5). I've read that Canonical was trying to update to bluez5 for 15.04 but couldn't get it ready in time.

**What You Can Do**

Well, there's hope! You can download the Bluez5 .deb file [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/amd64/bluez/download), if you need the AMD version, or [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/i386/bluez/download), if you need the i386 version, and then install it with `dpkg -i name_of_package.deb`. You'll then need to restart your computer.

This usually breaks the default bluetooth manager on Ubuntu but install **Bluetooth Manager**, either through Terminal or the Software Store, and you'll be able to connect all your devices.

Comment: Just tried [latest bluez](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/amd64/bluez/download) package from upcoming ubuntu release and it actually worked(I could send files to my smartphone) through **blueman** package. Good luck @Ludwik

Comment: Eric, thanks a lot for an elaborate answer (including the background info), and you were totally right! I've updated my bluez to 5.33, using the deb package provided by Yalok Iy (thanks for that too!). The mouse paired and started to work (even after awakening from suspension), however, only through blueman. When I open basic bluetooth app it is written that bluetooth is disabled (maybe that's what was called "broken bluetooth"). Did any of you had a similar problem?

Comment: Also in the dmesg I observed something new:

Comment: `code` [   41.320400] input: Dell WM615 Mouse as /devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:413C:8504.0003/input/input17 [   41.320608] hid-generic 0005:413C:8504.0003: input,hidraw2: BLUETOOTH HID v0.01 Mouse [Dell WM615 Mouse] on C4:8E:8F:F5:9B:D0 > [   49.763464] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=c4:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx SRC=192.168.0.104 DST=192.XXX.X.XXX LEN=65 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=42346 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=47899 DPT=18934 LEN=45 – @Eric Power @Yalok Iy

Comment: Based on this, I'll upgrade my own bluez later today and see if I can figure it out.

Comment: Yes, after upgrade, the connection worked only through blueman app, the standard bluetooth app fails.

Comment: Is there no way to make bluetooth app work? Blueman is working independently of the bluetooth app?

Comment: NB broken link at http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/amd64/bluez/download for 'wily'. There is a page for 'precise' http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/amd64/bluez/download