# Bluetooth keyboard (Microsoft Designer keyboard) fails to be added

Tags: 15.04, bluetooth, wireless-keyboards

My BT keyboard doesn't pair. Can you help me out?

Just bought [this very nice bluetooth desktop set](https://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/p/designer-bluetooth-desktop)
and [this Asus laptop](http://www.mycom.nl/laptops/laptops/576642/asus-n550jk-cm362h)
and installed Ubuntu 15.04 on it.

First my mouse didn't pair. I fixed that by 
installing Bluez5 and Bluetooth Manager,
as kindly suggested by [Eric Power](https://askubuntu.com/users/402909/eric-power) here:
[Bluetooth mouse pairs but does not connect](https://askubuntu.com/questions/661418/bluetooth-mouse-pairs-but-does-not-connect/)

Now the keyboard doesn't pair.

On the keyboard I press a small button for 3 secs to put it in pairing mode.
Bluetooth Manager sees the keyboard.
I click "setup".
BT Manager says to enter a code on the keyboard.
I enter that code on the keyboard and press ENTER: 
boom, the BT Manager says immediately "Failed to add device".

The final lines of /var/log/syslog are as below.
Thank you for your help!

```
last lines of /var/log/syslog:
bluetoothd[1144]: Error reading PNP_ID value: Attribute requires authentication before read/write
bluetoothd[1144]: Unable to register GATT service with handle 0x0011 for device FF:DE:BC:04:E4:E9:
org.blueman.Applet[1357]: ERROR:dbus.connection:Exception in handler for D-Bus signal:
org.blueman.Applet[1357]: Traceback (most recent call last):
org.blueman.Applet[1357]: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 230, in maybe_handle_message
org.blueman.Applet[1357]: self._handler(*args, **kwargs)
org.blueman.Applet[1357]: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/PropertiesBlueZInterface.py", line 51, in wrapper
org.blueman.Applet[1357]: handler(name, value, **kwargs)
org.blueman.Applet[1357]: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/SerialManager.py", line 48, in on_device_property_changed
org.blueman.Applet[1357]: d = Device(path)
org.blueman.Applet[1357]: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/main/Device.py", line 39, in __init__
org.blueman.Applet[1357]: self.Properties = self.Device.get_properties()
org.blueman.Applet[1357]: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/errors.py", line 143, in warp
org.blueman.Applet[1357]: raise parse_dbus_error(exception)
org.blueman.Applet[1357]: DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownObject: Method "GetAll" with signature "s" on interface "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" doesn't exist
bluetoothd[1144]: Unable to register GATT service with handle 0x0011 for device FF:DE:BC:05:E4:E9:
bluetoothd[1144]: Error reading PNP_ID value: Attribute requires authentication before read/write
bluetoothd[1144]: Error reading PNP_ID value: Attribute requires authentication before read/write
bluetoothd[1144]: Unable to register GATT service with handle 0x0011 for device FF:DE:BC:05:E4:E9:
bluetoothd[1144]: Report Map read failed: Attribute requires authentication before read/write
bluetoothd[1144]: Protocol Mode characteristic read failed: Attribute requires authentication before read/write
bluetoothd[1144]: HID Information read failed: Attribute requires authentication before read/write
bluetoothd[1144]: Read Report Reference descriptor failed: Attribute requires authentication before read/write
```

Comment: This is what worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04: https://askubuntu.com/a/1023532/815371

Answer (score 1):

This issue is due to the issue of gattool. The bluetoothd calls gattool 
to get attributes from the blue-tooth low energy device. Probably the device's firmware doesn't support the authentication protocol.

I avoid this issue by enabling the bluetooth experiment feature. add the "-E" options in your /etc/init.d/bluetooth, NOPLUGIN_OPTION="-E". Then, restart the bluetooth service.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me by updating bluez:

```
apt-add-repository ppa:vidplace7/bluez5
apt-add-repository ppa:blueman/ppa
apt-get update
apt-get install bluez
apt-get install blueman
apt-get install bluez-compat
```

Then I had to start bluez in experimental mode: Replace `/usr/sbin/bluetooth` by your own script:

```
#!/bin/sh
bluetooth -E
```

Now I can connect with the `blueman-applet` mouse and keyboard.

Any ideas how to connect automatically on startup or without using blueman (just command line)?

Answer (score 0):

For me, after attempting to pair the keyboard in Bluetooth Manager, I noticed a little notification bubble with a passcode.  The bubble is there for only a couple of seconds.  I typed the passcode on the keyboard and pressed Enter, and then the keyboard paired.

It took a couple of tries to get it to work (putting the keyboard back into pairing mode).