# How to get Rii mini BT keyboard to work under 16.04

Tags: keyboard, touchpad, bluetooth

I have connected the bluetooth [keyboard Rii mini i8+](http://www.riitek.com/product/i8x.html) to my Ubuntu 16.04 running on a NUC. I can find the keyboard, connect it, but it simply wont act as keyboard or mouse/trackpad.

Tried it on different hardware like Win7 and Firestick, works there like a charm.

Any idea?

Many thanks in advance,
Kazchen

Answer (score 2):

Kazchen,

I also have a Rii BT Keyboard that I tried connecting to Ubuntu 16.04. I ran into the same exact issues as you and went down the rabbit hole of messing with my bluetooth settings which is suggested on *all* forums regarding this question. However, it has nothing to do with bluetooth at all (even though I received a minor bluetooth error when connecting to the device). If you can press some of your numbers on the number key row and a few of the letters on the right side, such as Y or U, and see if it responds and gives you input. The input should be a random number between 1-9 that does not correspond to what is printed on your keys. If you can reproduce that exactly, here are the steps to fix the issue:

- Plug in a secondary keyboard to USB (do not disconnect bluetooth)
- Numlock should be automatically turned on. Turn it off.
- Voila! May require restart.

Comment: Awesome! Turning off numlock worked for me. This should be the accepted answer. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I got one working connected to a friends R-Pi (not running 16.04 though). These were the steps (from my notes):

Open a terminal and enter the following commands

```
sudo bluetoothctl -a
power on
agent KeyboardOnly
default-agent
pairable on
```

Enter discovery mode on your keyboard

```
scan on
```

You should see your keyboard appear on the list. Copy its MAC address (**xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx**) to the clipboard.

Now type

```
pair MAC_ADDRESS
trust MAC_ADDRESS
connect MAC_ADDRESS
```

where MAC_ADDRESS is the address you copied to the clipboard.

You should see something like:

```
[bluetooth]# connect xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
Attempting to connect to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
[CHG] Device xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx Connected: yes
Connection successful
```

Now type:

```
quit
```

I can't remember where I found the guide, but hopefully that will work for you too.

Comment: Tried that, but no joy for me. It is connected and trusted, but it won't move a thing :(

Comment: @Kazchen I read on [another post](https://askubuntu.com/a/836596/682481) that upgrading to 16.10 worked for them (albeit with a different Bluetooth keyboard!). If you are able to upgrade, this may be worth trying with yours?