# Can't login or do a recovery boot since I uninstalled bluetooth

Tags: boot, bluetooth, bluez

I was trying to get a new bluetooth keyboard and mouse working on my Ubuntu 14.04 laptop and have managed to totally mess up my system. I am wondering what my options are.

I was following this guide: [Microsoft Designer Mouse (Bluetooth 4.0) on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/646433/microsoft-designer-mouse-bluetooth-4-0-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts) and wasn't having much luck. I uninstalled all the packages I had installed and then tried to revert, but my system crashed (the mouse froze) and I had to restart. The system couldn't shutdown properly and didn't start up properly either (both hung)

These are my issues:

(1) When I start up Ubuntu, it hangs on the loading screen

(2) When I go into recovery mode, and try to manually install `bluez` via `apt-get`, then I see the following error:

```
runlevel:/var/run/utmp: No such file or directory
reload: Unknown instance:
invoke-rc.d: initscript dbus, action "force-reload" failed.
runlevel: /var/run/utmp: No such file or directory
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript bluetooth, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package bluez (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 bluez
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I manually created an empty utmp file, but get the same error as above without the utmp lines.

```
sudo cat /dev/null > /var/run/utmp
```

(3) When I try enable "Network" from the Recovery menu, it hangs after displaying the error:

```
ModemManager[14367]: <warn> Couldn't find support for device at '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:08:00.0': not supported by any plugin
```

It looks like the missing plugin is causing the OS to hang when it is loading ...

What are my options at this point?

Any suggestions will be gratefully received....